# How to detect if a new issue is a clone issue

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I need to detect if a new issue is a clone issue.

Although I can’t use the listener for it. The “Cloners” issue link isn’t added at the time the issueCreated event is handled by the listener and I haven’t IssueLinkCreatedEvent because the Jira version is 7.2.
I tried to do post function for step Create. It executes last after “Fire a Issue created event that can be processed by the listener”, Although, issue link isn’t added at this time yet too.

```
@Scanned
public class TestFunction extends AbstractJiraFunctionProvider {
private IssueLinkManager issueLinkManager;
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestFunction.class);

public TestFunction(CustomFieldManager customFieldManager) {
    this.issueLinkManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueLinkManager();
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Override
public void execute(Map transientVars, Map args, PropertySet ps) throws WorkflowException {

    try {
        MutableIssue mutableIssue = getIssue(transientVars);
        if (mutableIssue == null) {
            return;
        }

        logger.debug("mutableIssue.getKey() = " + mutableIssue.getKey());
        logger.debug("mutableIssue.getId() = " + mutableIssue.getId());
        logger.debug("getInwardLinks size = " + ComponentAccessor.getIssueLinkManager().getInwardLinks(mutableIssue.getId()).size());
        logger.debug("getOutwardLinks size = " + ComponentAccessor.getIssueLinkManager().getOutwardLinks(mutableIssue.getId()).size());

        ApplicationUser  applicationUser = ComponentAccessor.getJiraAuthenticationContext().getLoggedInUser();

        logger.debug("applicationUser.getUsername() = " + applicationUser.getUsername());

        LinkCollection linkCollection = ComponentAccessor.getIssueLinkManager().getLinkCollection(
                mutableIssue,
                applicationUser);

        logger.debug("linkCollection.getLinkTypes().size()  = " + linkCollection.getLinkTypes().size());
        logger.debug("linkCollection.getAllIssues().size()  = " + linkCollection.getAllIssues().size());
    }

    catch(Exception exception) {
        logger.error("exception = ", exception); 

    }
}
}
```

Size of Inward links, Outward links are 0 and size of linkTypes and issues of linkCollection are 0 too.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to add the Cloners link type to Admin, Issue Link Types by hand